# FFMPEG duplicating the first frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to use FFMPEG (the latest version) to cut a 24 fps matroska file. So I am using -ss and -t, but I noticed with VLC that the very first frame is ALWAYS duplicated one time, no matter the file or the duration I choose. While it is not a really serious issue, but I wanted to know if there was a way to prevent that.

Here is the command I am using:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:26.086 -i file.mkv -t 00:00:02.000 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

add  `-vsync vfr` in your cmd may be helpful

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:26.086 -i file.mkv  -vsync vfr -t 00:00:02.000 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mp4`

Comment: why did that solve the issue?

Comment: From the ffmpeg docs: ```[When using the vfr option, frames] are passed through with their timestamp or dropped so as to prevent 2 frames from having the same timestamp.``` https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html